# Bulk create users in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create users in bulk by following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/users-bulk-add

I logged into Azure Portal with the following account:

[image]

I created a csv file with the following details:

[image]

I see the following error message:

The user name in the uploaded file is not valid. Change the user name in the uploaded file to be a valid user name in your Azure AD. Ensure the domain portion of the user name is verified in your Azure AD  or is the initial domain name (like *.onmicrosoft.com). Then resubmit your request.

What am I missing? Am I using an account that is a User administrator in the organization? How do I verify that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were whitespaces in the beginning of User Name field. After removing whitespaces, I was able to upload csv file successfully.

Comment: Facepalm. This is so silly, Microsoft's template itself includes examples with the leading white spaces in every other field. `Example: Chris Green, chris@contoso.com, myPassword1234, No`. And has no trailing 13 commas at the end. The correct entry should start from 4th line and should be:  `Chris Green,chris@contoso.com,myPassword1234,No,Cris,Green,,,,,,,,,,,`

Answer (score 0):

For Now Azure Does not let "bulk create"  users other than verified domain and b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com .

You can look more about this feature here : https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/41804

Comment: Thank you! Can you give examples of b2ctenant and verified domain?

Comment: @user989988 I think this question is answered here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59463. Please let us know if you need additional help

Comment: Thanks. There were whitespaces in the beginning of User Name field.